# How to use self joining associations in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have two simple factories:

```
factory :parent_category, :class => Category do 
  name "Garden"
  parent_id 0
  display_order 1
 end

factory :category do
  association           :parent_id, factory: :parent_category
  name                  "Tools"
  associated_categories ""
  postfix_to_display    ''
  display_order         1
end
```

However, when I try to generate a factory using:

```
f = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for #<Category:0x007fdf50495c00>
```

I am using Rails 3.2.12 and FactoryGirl 4.2.

Comment: Can we take a look at the associations in your `Category` model?

Comment: Your question helped me build a FactoryGirl with an inner join association properly. I had done what you needed to fix your issue but not what you had done to create your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
factory :category do
  association :parent, factory: :parent_category
  ...
end
```

Comment: new error: NoMethodError: undefined method `parent=' for #<Category:0x007faed4f9aff8>

Comment: How are your associations set up in the models?

Comment: my Category model was missing a self-joining relationship, I added the following 'belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"' & used the solution provided by gylaz...now it works, thanks guys! :)

Comment: @gylaz can you have a look  on 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940681/build-factories-for-self-referential-associations-in-rails